# Find/Replace part of text in PHP and convert to HTML

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a large number of ASCII text files and am listing out the contents of each using the code below:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$orig = file_get_contents($file);
$a =htmlentities($orig);
echo $a;
?>
```

Some strings of text in each ASCII file are references to file names of other files and I'm trying to **find and replace them with a Hyperlink** to that file.

For example, a text file might be called "LAB_E143.txt" which looks like this:

```
LAB_E143:
        LDX   $#FF          ; load X with $FF
        JSR   LAB_E151      ; jump to this location
```

and what I'm trying to find & replace are references beginning with "LAB_" (e.g. LAB_E151 in the example above) so that it displays the text as a Hyperlink with a href of:

```
http:\\capture.php?file=lab_e151.txt
```

Clicking on that link will then display the contents of that particular text file and so on. **All the references begin with "LAB_" followed by 4 variable characters**.

I've tried str_replace but am struggling to parse the 4 variable characters each time.

Any help / pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you initially trying to get a list of file names starting with LAB_ or do you already have that list? Then after that are you trying to display those files for users to click to view the contents?

Comment: Hi - I have the list of files already, all beginning with 'LAB_xxxx.txt' - if a users selects LAB_E143 for example and inside that file are references to LAB_E151, then I'd like the text LAB_E151 to be clickable so the user can then read the contents of that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **Regex** for such cases. As shudder mentioned, [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) should be the best function to use for this purpose.

1. Detect all references with the following Regex: `/LAB_(?<id>\S{4})/`
2. Write a function to replace the matches with the `<a>` tag

That's it.

```
$text = 'LAB_8435 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. LAB_8337 Amet.';

$formattedText = preg_replace_callback('/LAB_(?<id>\S{4})/',  function ($matches) {
    return '<a href="/capture.php?id='.$matches[1].'">'.$matches[0].'</a>';
}, $text);

echo $formattedText;
```

Comment: No problem. I improved the answer now a little bit, Would be nice if you could accept the answer.

Comment: That is superb - really, thank you. In fact thanks to all that responded. First time using Stackoverflow.com and am blown away by you guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: you want to display file from specific folder - make sure that user can't change the path with provided string (file whitelist, filename sanitization), because it would be possible to do some serious damage.

I suggest not giving a clue that link is directly connected with included file name. Instead `/capture.php?file=lab_e151.txt` you may have `/capture.php?id=e151` and then something like this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''; //in php7: $id = $_GET['id'] ?? ''; 
if (!preg_match('/[0-9A-Za-z]{4}/', $id)) { die('Invalid link'); }
$file = 'lab_' . $id . '.txt';

//...

$convertToLink = function ($matches) {
    return '<a href="/capture.php?id=' . strtolower($matches[1]) . '">' . $matches[0] . '</a>';
};

$code = preg_replace_callback('/LAB_([0-9A-Za-z]{4})/', $convertToLink, $string);

echo '<pre>' . $code . '</pre>';
```

If those 4 chars are hex number then you may use this pattern instead: `/LAB_([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})/`

Comment: Many thanks for replying, will give that a go. Much appreciated

Comment: +1 regarding sanitising the file paths.  If you've not done it before, a fairly quick/easy/hacky method: $trustedPath = realpath('../somewhere/'); $untrustedPath = realpath($_UNTRUSTED['path']); if ($untrustedPath === false || substr(($untrustedPath), 0, strlen($trustedPath)) !== $trustedPath) die();